# Printing arrays, setting up arrays

Tags: java, arrays

My code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class IT106_Playlist {

  public static void main(String[] args){

  final int MAX_SONGS = 106;
  int totalDuration = 0;
  int numSongs=0;
  boolean exitVar=false;
  int i=0;

  String[] songTitles = new String[MAX_SONGS];
  int[] songLengths = new int[MAX_SONGS];

  while(exitVar==false && numSongs<=songTitles.length) {

     if (songTitles.equals("-1")){
        exitVar=true;
     }

  do{

     songTitles[numSongs] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a song name, or type -1 to exit");
     if (!songTitles.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Please enter a valid song name, or type -1 to exit");
     }else{
     ++numSongs;
   }
  }while(!songTitles[numSongs].equals(""));

  do{
    try{ 
     songLengths[numSongs] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a song length, e.g. 4, or type -1 to exit"));
     }catch (NumberFormatException e){
           songLengths[numSongs]=-1;
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: please enter a valid song length, e.g. 4, or type -1 to exit");
     }       
           totalDuration+=songLengths[numSongs];

  /* line 41 */ }while(songLengths[numSongs]=-1);

  boolean addMore=true;

  while((numSongs<=MAX_SONGS) && (addMore=true)){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Song #" + i + ": "+ songTitles[i] + " length: " + songLengths[i] + "\n");
     i++;
    if(songTitles[i] ==null){
    addMore=false;
   }
  }
 }
}
}
```

Hi. I am trying to figure out why I have an error on line 41 of my code saying int cannot be converted to boolean, and I wanted to know why/how to fix this.

Basically, I am making a playlist. The user enters the song name and length separately(two different arrays) and then once they either reach the max amount of songs, or they wish to exit, they can do so by typing -1.

Then, the user can remove songs from their playlist, and then after that they can exit, printing all of the songs and the total duration, as well as the total number of songs.

We cannot use arrayLists, or any methods.

My question is, 1. is my setup okay, and 2. how do I make the songs print after each song name has been entered? I am so close to figuring this out..Thank you!

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Don't do it by hand, let your editor(IDE) do it for you (it is very easy to manually make mistakes). Also post full error message and point to line which is causing it.

Comment: Okay, one second, sorry

Comment: Anyway it looks like error is caused by `while (songLengths[numSongs] = -1);` where you are using `=` (assignment) instead of `==`(comparison). `while` can contain expression which can be evaluated to `boolean` (not other types like `int` - Java is not C where `1` represents `true`).

Comment: Ah, yes , I fixed this. Now, I get a NullPointerException at line 30 after I fixed this. No matter what input I put for the name of the song, I get an error message and if I type -1, it keeps me in the loop still. I can't leave it.

Answer (score 2):

Caution, there are two problems here.  One of them is the one showing an error involving the song lengths, this is what it should be:

```
while (songLengths[numSongs] == -1);
```

You also have a hidden bug a couple lines down, where you run `while ((numSongs <= MAX_SONGS) && (addMore = true))`.  This is *assigning* `addMore` to `true`, you want to run `(addMore == true)` to compare.

EDIT Just found the error dealing with line 30.  You are checking if an `String[]` equals a `""` like so: `if (!songTitles.equals("")) {`.  This is incorrect, and you also are `!`ing it, you want to check `if (songTitles[numSongs].equals("")) {`.

EDIT 2 Turns out that wasn't the entire problem with line 30.  In your `do while`, at that line, you have A) A `!` where you don't want it, and B) if the user does enter in a proper song name, previously in the `do while`, you incremented `numSongs`, now you need to get the previous one to compare like so:

```
} while (songTitles[numSongs-1].equals(""));
```

EDIT 3 & 4 I've now fully read the code, and here is what I think you are looking for.  I've put in comments explaining some of the main changes.  Also, now handling the no `System.exit(0);` usage.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class IT106_Playlist {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int MAX_SONGS = 106;
        int totalDuration = 0;
        int numSongs = 0;
        boolean exitVar = false;
        int i = 0;

        String[] songTitles = new String[MAX_SONGS];
        int[] songLengths = new int[MAX_SONGS];

        while (numSongs <= songTitles.length) {
            // Removed your check to see if the song name is -1, and placed it later on
            do {

                songTitles[numSongs] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        "Enter a song name, or type -1 to exit");
                if (songTitles[numSongs].equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: Please enter a valid song name, or type -1 to exit");
                } else if (songTitles[numSongs].equals("-1")) { // Checks if -1
                    exitVar = true;
                    System.exit(0); // This is how to quickly exit your program safely
                }
            } while (songTitles[numSongs].equals("")); // Keep asking the user for input if they don't provide any

            if (exitVar) {
                break;
            }

            do {
                try {
                    songLengths[numSongs] = Integer
                            .parseInt(JOptionPane
                                    .showInputDialog(null,
                                            "Enter a song length, e.g. 4."));
                    if (songLengths[numSongs] > 0) { // Check if the length is more than 0 (assuming no songs are 0 in length)
                        totalDuration += songLengths[numSongs]; // Add to totalDuration only if it is a valid length
                    } else { // If song length is invalid, display error
                        songLengths[numSongs] = -1;
                        JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Error: please enter a valid song length, e.g. 4.");
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // Catch if could not parse int
                    songLengths[numSongs] = -1;
                    JOptionPane
                            .showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Error: please enter a valid song length, e.g. 4.");
                }

            } while (songLengths[numSongs] <= 0); // Only do this if you don't have a valid song length

            boolean addMore = true;

            while ((numSongs <= MAX_SONGS) && (addMore == true)) { // addMore bug fixed
                // This is my addition, but to be more user friendly, I put in (i+1), so that the user doesn't question what "Song #0" is
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Song #" + (i+1) + ": "
                        + songTitles[i] + " length: " + songLengths[i] + "\n");
                i++;
                if (songTitles[i] == null) {
                    addMore = false;
                }
            }
            numSongs++; // Moved this way down here to avoid messing code up above
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just changed that, and I get this error: addMore==false; is not a statement

Comment: @NickRichardson  I was referring to the `while ((numSongs <= MAX_SONGS) && (addMore = true))` portion.  I never said anything about equaling `false`...

Comment: Thank you gilderman! I just noticed that. Now when I try to enter anything for song name, it just shows an error message, then shows me the length input. After entering both, it shows the print message, but if you do multiple inputs, it just erases the last two inputs and shows the two most recent.

Comment: Could this be caused by my code within the try/catch block? I just realized the error message always appears because maybe I haven't put it inside of an if statement.

Comment: @NickRichardson  I just found that too, check my edit. :)  I can enter in multiple songs, but not quit.  You are not checking for the -1 input to quit, you may wish to put that in. :)

Comment: On line 18, I thought I did. I just changed it to

   if (songTitles[numSongs].equals("-1")){
            
       exitVar=true;
         }

and that just resulted in me getting a nullpointerexception. Should I just rewrite this entire thing?

Comment: @NickRichardson  Okay, I now have the full code edited, check my answer now, see what you think.

Comment: @Gilderman thank you!! One thing: I cannot use system.exit to leave the program (dumb, I know) so I had to use the -1 thingy to escape. I need to add that in somehow..

Comment: Oh yeah, I just read my assignment again: Apparently, I have to list all songs that have been entered so far, not just the newest one. Then, they have to remove songs, and after that, a list of all the songs will appear.

I just tried entering in -1 for either input, and nothing happens

Comment: @NickRichardson  Well, give that a shot, and if you have a specific problem, please open a new question.  I hope I answered your original question though.  When I run it, and I enter in -1 for the song name, it exits, not sure why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just tried typing -1 for the title input and it didnt exit the loop. I will open a new question .. thank you so much sir, I am basically halfway there now :)

Comment: Okay, I am still getting that issue where typing -1 for the songTitle doesnt get me out of the loop, and my print message at the end still shows only the newest entries.

Comment: Oh..I dont have break in my code. I am not allowed to use break. That is why. How do I get around that?

Comment: @NickRichardson As this is apparently a class, I will not provide as much information.  The reason you are not getting out of the loop is due to Java's garbage collection, it runs when it feels like, see my video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAZSD7oTvx4) comparing this with using `System.exit(0);`.  If you are not allowed to use `break`, then simply `!` the `exitVar`, and use it to not run the rest of the code.  Why can you not use `break` or `System.exit(0);`?  I use them all the time in my programs...

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
   }while(songLengths[numSongs]=-1);
```

perhaps supposed to be

```
   }while(songLengths[numSongs]==-1);
```

The former is always assigning the value `-1` to `songLengths[numSongs]`, which results in an integer value and in Java this won't convert to a boolean.

You also probably meant `while((numSongs<=MAX_SONGS) && addmore)`.

Comment: Ah, yes , I fixed this. Now, I get a NullPointerException at line 30 after I fixed this. No matter what input I put for the name of the song, I get an error message and if I type -1, it keeps me in the loop still. I can't leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line is the culprit:

```
while(songLengths[numSongs]=-1);
```

What you seem to want there should actually be:

```
while(songLengths[numSongs] == -1);
```

A single `=` means to assign a value; a double `==` is for comparing values.

Comment: Ah, yes , I fixed this. Now, I get a NullPointerException at line 30 after I fixed this. No matter what input I put for the name of the song, I get an error message and if I type -1, it keeps me in the loop still. I can't leave it.